# Is it possible to use Quantum Monte Carlo for non local interactions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, non-locality

I just have a brief question about QMC being applied to calculating expectation values. If I were to calculate the expectation value of an operator, like the energy via a Quantum Mote Carlo approximation. I can take the expectation value, and convert it into a sum of `local' values which are sampled proportionally to $\vert \Psi \vert^{2}$

$$ E = \frac{\langle \Psi \vert \hat{H} \vert \Psi \rangle}{\langle \Psi \vert \Psi \rangle} \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{1}{\Psi(x_i)}\hat{H}\Psi(x_i) \ \textrm{where} \ x_i \sim \vert \Psi \vert^{2}$$

However, this only works if the operator in question is `local'. So, here's my question. Is it all possible to do QMC calculations for 'non-local' operators? Like a non-local interaction?

Thank you in advance!